# swift dictionary population issue: type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, dictionary, declaration

I am trying to migrate the next code from Objetive-C to Swift:

```
   NSArray *voices = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices];
    NSArray *languages = [voices valueForKey:@"language"];

    NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *code in languages)
    {
        dictionary[code] = [currentLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:code];
    }
```

And I did the following:

```
var voices:NSArray = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
var languages:NSArray=voices.valueForKey("language") as NSArray

var currentLocale:NSLocale=NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrentLocale()
var dictionary:NSMutableDictionary=NSMutableDictionary()

for code in languages {
   var name=currentLocale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: code)
   dictionary[code]=name
}
```

and I am getting the following error:

**error: type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'
    dictionary[code]=name**

I don’t know how to declare the dictionary object, to do something as simple as an array with country codes strings as key and a small description. 
like

dictionary[“es-ES"]=[“Spanish”]
   dictionary[“en-US"]=[“American English”]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSDictionary` keys need to conform to `NSCopying`, but `AnyObject` doesn't necessarily. (`NSArray` returns `AnyObject`s in Swift.) Use the `as!` operator on your `code` variable to be sure that it is:

```
dictionary[code as! NSCopying] = name
```

You can also downcast the `language` array to `[String]` and avoid the cast in the assignment code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, 

dictionary[code as! NSCopying]=name returns Error “Expected , separator”

I am testing this on a playground, you just need to import AVFoundation to test.  
Regarding the downcast of languages, I wonder if you can help me on that, I am starting with swift and I am quite lost.

Comment: Sorry, use as. As! is Swift 1.2 and only works in Xcode 6.3 and above.

Comment: As you imply, the better solution is to downcast the language array to the correct type, `var languages = voices.valueForKey("language") as [String]`