# retrieving firebase data for iOS app using swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm using firebase to collect data, and i'm trying to retrieve the data in a usable format for an iPhone app, and i can't quite get it out properly. I'm writing the app in Swift.

The data is grouped by a date string then the with a random key and then the data. Eg:

```
{
  "20160304" : {
    "-KC-aOwSWpt4dlYmjJE4" : {
      "coordinates" : "-37.7811465912404, 145.005993055861",
      "event" : "Test event",
      "time" : "2016-03-04 07:48:43 +0000"
    }, etc...
```

I'm so far grabbing the data like this:

```
ref.queryOrderedByKey().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
        snapshot in
        //print(snapshot.key) // date
        print(snapshot.value)
    })
```

And it returns something like this to the console:

```
{
"-KD8O0gL7gDGu_hRyFzQ" =     {
    coordinates = "-37.7540958861003, 145.001224694195";
    event = "Test event";
    time = "2016-03-18 11:02:32 +0000";
}; etc...
```

Does anyone know how i can get down to the next level, past the random keys, to the meaningful data? I had trouble before with this for javascript, but it's confusing me using swift.
I'd like to be able to grab the detailed data (bottom level) for a defined date (top level).

Comment: May I ask: do you have multiple random keys under each date node? There may be some benefit to swapping that around and have the node name be the random key and the date stored as a child. The date is already contained in the time child node so that may be redundant. Do you query by 'time'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
let jsonLocations = snapshot.valueInExportFormat() as! NSDictionary
let keys = jsonLocations.allKeys

for key in keys {
    let json = jsonLocations[key] as! [String: AnyObject]
    self.sections.append(Location(JSONObject: json))
}
```

Comment: @Richie you can use same method for each "json" and it will just put you one level deeper

Comment: thanks. now i get 'Argument type 'AnyObject' does not conform to expected type 'NSCopying'? .. also it doesn't know 'Location'

Comment: @Richie in your case you have only 1 child added, but my code will also work in case you will have multiple entries

Comment: `ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
            snapshot in
            let jsonLocations = snapshot.valueInExportFormat() as! NSDictionary
            let keys = jsonLocations.allKeys
            
            for key in keys {
                let json = jsonLocations[key] as! [String: AnyObject]
                self.sections.append(Location(JSONObject: json))
            }
 
        })`

Comment: @Richie check out answer to this question, it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610516/swift-dictionary-population-issue-type-anyobject-does-not-conform-to-protocol

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting there now

Answer (score 2):

I usually try to stick to methods of [`FDatasnapshot`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FDataSnapshot.html) as long as possible, which leads to:

```
ref.queryOrderedByKey().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        print(child.key); // -KC-aOwSWpt4dlYmjJE4
        print(child.childSnapshotForPath("event").value)
    }
});
```